# FBDialogs.presentShareDialogWithLink callback never triggered

Tags: ios, facebook, swift, callback, handler

I am unable to get the Facebook share dialog to callback correctly. As far as I can tell I have set up my handler correctly. The share is successful but the callback is never triggered.

Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks.

```
        if FBDialogs.canPresentShareDialogWithParams(params) {
            FBDialogs.presentShareDialogWithLink(params.link, handler: { (fbAppCall : FBAppCall!, [NSObject : AnyObject]!, error : NSError!) -> Void in
                println("Do stuff")
            })
        }
```